# DRUPAL broken images after enabling url rewriting

Tags: drupal, url-rewriting, broken-image

I turned on URL rewriting on Drupal, and some URL image are broken.

For example :

local/tw/sites/all/themes/tw/images/1-p1.jpg  become
local/tw/content/sites/all/themes/tw/images/1-p1.jpg

or

local/tw/sites/all/themes/tw/images/2-p1.jpg become 
local/tw/node/sites/all/themes/tw/images/2-p1.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: How're you outputting your images in your templates?

Answer (score 0):

If you used relative path, and you're talking about contents within nodes, it's perfectly normal, since "node/" is interpreted like a directory.

You could fix this problem adding a "/" before image src, or using module like [Path Filter](http://drupal.org/project/pathfilter) that provides a simple file:relative/path/to/file syntax.